# Partition Over issue in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate, partition

I have a Order shipment table like below -

| Order_ID | shipment_id | pkg_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 5 |
| 1 | 101 | 5 |
| 1 | 101 | 5 |
| 1 | 102 | 3 |
| 1 | 102 | 3 |

I want the output table to look like below -

| Order_ID | Distinct_shipment_id | total_pkg_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |

```
select 
   order_id
 , count(distinct(shipment_id)
 , avg(pkg_weight) over (partition by shipment_id)
 
from table1
group by  order_id
```

but getting the below error -

> column "pkg_weight" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in
> an aggregate function

Please help

Comment: What rdbms (oracle, sql server, mysql) are you using?

Comment: What does 8 as total_pkg_weight mean? I'd say the total weight is 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a distinct select first, then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT Order_ID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT shipment_id) AS Distinct_shipment_id,
       SUM(pkg_weight) AS total_pkg_weight
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Order_ID, shipment_id, pkg_weight
    FROM table1
) t
GROUP BY Order_ID;
```